# Error creating form within a dynamically created table via javascript/ajax php

Tags: javascript, php, forms, file, html-table

The problem I have is `var myFileList = document.getElementById('upload_file').files;` is not getting the files and not carrying on any further in the code when I try and get the information I have "dynamically created" by my PHP file. However, if I make the same table within my HTML page and append the form to the table, the code is working perfectly.

To summarize: Because the table is coming from PHP, the form doesn't work.

My col in the PHP which the form will be `appendChild` to is done like this:

```
$display_String .= '<td><div id = "image'.$f1.'"></div></td>';
```

And the JavaScript which makes the form is:

```
    var f = document.createElement("form");
f.setAttribute('enctype',"multipart/form-data");
f.setAttribute('method',"post");
f.setAttribute('action',"uploadImage.php");


var i = document.createElement("input"); //input element, text
i.setAttribute('type',"file");
i.setAttribute('name',"upload_file");
i.setAttribute('id',"upload_file");
i.setAttribute('size',4);

f.appendChild(i);
document.getElementById("image1").appendChild(f);
```

"image1" is the name of the div in the php table,
As I said if I create the table statically within the html file like this it works fine

```
    <table>
    <tr>
        <td>test </td>
        <td> bah </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>  
        <td> <div id ="image1">  </div> </td>
        <td> col2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>  
        <td></td>
        <td> col2 </td>
    </tr>
    </table>
```

I know it will be something really simple,
 also sorry I cannot use JQuery for this.

Answer (score 0):

try to put it in a function that is executed when the document is loaded.

```
document.onload = doYourThing();

function doYourThing() {
    //Your code here
}
```

Comment: It already is, the document loads then the user searches for something where the table comes from. Then the user clicks edit and the form comes up. Sorry should have made that clear

Comment: Anyone else have any idea?